# Read excel 2007 file with OLEDB using a specific culture

Tags: .net, excel-2007

I am trying to read an excel 2007 file (using OLEDB) that has dates in the UK format.
The server is (sometimes) set to US format and so the normal date format problems are in play.

This is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myfile.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"
```

I want to ensure that the file is always opened using the en-GB culture. Is there a way to specify the culture using the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Locale Identifier=2057` to your connection-string. 2057 is `en-gb`. It may not work on your provider, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah we tried that one already. From the docs I have read it seems to indicate that "Local Identifier" is a JET setting, we are using the ACE driver as that is what supports Excel 2007 files.